# HTML and Javascript. Why does my code not work

Tags: javascript, html

This is a quite simple piece of HTML with a bit of JavaScript integrated. I did what I could from what I know, but I don't think I used the correct document tags. Its either that or the page needs a way of updating, which I don't know how to do. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="">
        User name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="userid">
        <br>
        User password:<br>
        <input type="password" name="psw">
    </form>

    <p>The characters in a password field are masked (shown as asterisks or circles).</p>

    <p id="enter"></p>

    <script>
        function access(username, password) {
            if (username == "bobby") {
                if (password == "qwertyasd123") {
                    document.getElementById(enter).innerHTML = "You may pass";
                }
            }
        }
        access(document.getElementsByName("userid").innerHTML, 
            document.getElementsByName("userid").innerHTML)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you calling the function of page load , I think you want to call the `access` function on some event

Comment: You will want to `name` your `form` and use `document.forms[formname].userid.value`, (and `.psw.value`), and you'll also want to keep the username and password secret - use a server side script (Bash, Perl, PHP, Python, JavaScript) or program (C, Java, C#,...).

Comment: @Kenney How do you use Java in HTML/JS?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what your code currently does, what errors it produces if any, and what the desired behavior is. For more information please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
document.getElementById(enter)
```

to

```
document.getElementById('enter')
```

Also change:

```
document.getElementsByName("userid").innerHTML
```

to

```
document.getElementsByName("userid")[0].value
```

And you didn't change userid to psw for one your strings.

Answer (score 0):

there where quite some mistakes indeed:

of `document.getElementsByName("userid")` you get an list, so you want to access the first by `[0]`:

```
document.getElementsByName("userid")
```

You forgot to use the id as a string here: `document.getElementById(enter)` should be  `document.getElementById("enter")`

You used `"userid"` twice and not `"psw"` aswell:

```
access(document.getElementsByName("userid")[0].value, 
            document.getElementsByName("psw")[0].value)
```

You want it to happen when you press enter:

```
<form onsubmit='access(document.getElementsByName("userid")[0].value, document.getElementsByName("psw")[0].value)'>
```

and you will need a `<input type="submit" name="sub">` for that aswell.

**Here is the complete code and the working example**: https://jsfiddle.net/j35fbet9/

Comment: Thanks all. I understand the issues now. Very basic errors from me, although I am fairly weak at coding myself.